# Is there a way to put a permanent space into an input field?

Tags: html, css, web

I have an input field and when the user clicks into it, I would like the type cursor line to appear one space into the input box. Is there a way to force a space at the start of an input field with css and/or html? I know this is possible with javascript but if there is one, I would like to use a css/html-only way.

I have tried inserting a space using the "content" attribute but that didn't work. Or maybe I am not doing it correctly. Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<input class="input-test" type="text" value="" placeholder="test">
```

**CSS**

```
.input-test:before{
    content: " ";
}
```

**EDIT:**
This can be accomplished by adding padding on the left. I know, embarrassingly simple. Thanks to Yuriy Galanter.

Comment: any specific reason for a space at the beginning? you should try something like padding or margins.

Comment: css can't control the cursor position. This is something you'll need javascsript for.

Comment: @MarcB, see Yuriy's answer below.

Comment: Ah. You just wanted some "visual space". I thought you wanted an actual space character.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like:

```
.input-test{
    padding-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: Use `1em` to be font-size-independent.

Comment: this is a better choice because it leaves the place-holder text also intact.

Comment: D'oh, sometimes the simplest solution is the one I'm most prone to overlook. Thanks for that!

Comment: @user1457366 Glad this worked for you. Please mark as answer if solution was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input class="input-test" type="text" value=" " placeholder="test">
```

Just give it a default value of " " - with a space in it. Works for me. =)

Comment: You are correct. The placeholder in that case would not appear.

Comment: Yep, tried that. As noted, the spaceholder value is overridden.